# I made a login page ,After I put in the login credentials, the page is not moving to the next page

Tags: python, django

when I try to login to the page, it is not moving onto the next page. The project is linked to a db and the db stores the superuser data, but the login is not moving further

**login_page.html :**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Student Management System | Log in</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" %}">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" %}">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "dist/css/adminlte.min.css" %}">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Student</b> Management System</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to Student Management System</p>

      <form action="/doLogin" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>

      <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{% static "plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="{% static "plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" %}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{% static "dist/js/adminlte.min.js" %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from student_management_app import views
from student_management_system import settings


urlpatterns = [
    url('demo',views.showDemoPage),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('',views.ShowLoginPage),
    url('doLogin',views.doLogin),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The doLogin function is supposed to output the login credentials entered in the login page, but it is not going to the output part of it

**views.py :**

```
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

from django.shortcuts import render

def showDemoPage(request):
    return render(request,"demo.html")

def ShowLoginPage(request):
    return render(request,"login_page.html")

def doLogin(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Method not Allowed</h2>")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Email : "+request.POST.get("email")+" Password : "+request.POST.get("password"))
```

Comment: Hey there, you need to mention a little more details, show us the complete HTML code of that page, then it will make it a little more clear as to what has to happen. I will be happy to help you if you provide me with those details.

Comment: yes, i will edit the .html
The main problem I have is when i put in the login credentials and press the Signin button, the page has to return a Http response of the doLogin function, which is not happening @RajatShenoi

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can try to do is put a Login redirect URL in the settings.py file.

```html
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```